# GNOME 3 search bar with no results

Tags: 16.04, gnome-shell, search, activities-overview

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME 3 on my laptop. I use my laptop for university work, so often times I find myself using the search function of Gnome to get to certain class folders quickly. I've run into the issue where I get "No Results" when searching for a folder I know exists and have searched for many times.

I went to Settings and found the Search tab. There is an option to check on/off the different results you want to show up, "Files" being one of them. Within the Files option, you can add what folders you want to show up specifically. Even after I put the folders I want in, the search bar continues to come up with no results.

I have "Files" selected:
[image]

I specifically want to search for my "scripts" directory, so I add it to the search locations:
[image]

I type in "scripts" and it doesn't show up:
[image]

What can I do here? Is there a simple fix I'm just missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset `tracker` by

```
tracker reset -r
```

Then do the indexing again by

```
tracker daemon -s
```

Log out and log in again.

Comment: Are you sure this is still valid on 18.04? Doesn't seems to work for me, although on terminal `tracker search something` return me some results. Maybe now is mandatory [Tracker-Search extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/284/tracker-search/)? BTW it returns error while trying to install it.

Comment: @pablo I don't know (and I *never claimed so*); I'm using 16.04 just like OP here.