# Add filename search into the gnome-shell bar

Tags: gnome-shell

I'm using 17.10 and I would like to search for file names from the gnome-shell search bar.  Is there a way to turn this on?

If I open up a file manager (nautilus) and search for a filename, it finds what I want, but I'd like to have those results show up right from that easily accessible search.

Thanks!

### Update

In response to pomskey's answer:

This pointed me down a good path, but it's not working in 17.10 strictly (this is a fresh install of artful, not an upgrade).

1. tracker is no longer installed, so I tried to install that and configure it according to your linked question, and it never quite worked correctly.
2. There seems to be a built-in file search in gnome-shell now, but it does not look in subfolders.  For instance, place a file called 'paste.txt' in your home folder at the root, and one in your Dropbox.  It finds the `/home/user/paste.txt`, but not `/home/user/Dropbox/paste.txt`.

This appears to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1732780

Which sucks.  Also, tracker doesn't seem to work quite right with gnome-shell.  This bug explores some of that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1666676

In the end, I am unable to use file search like it worked in Unity. :/

Answer (score 2):

Open **Settings**, go to the *Search* section and toggle on "*Files*".

Then click on the gear symbol at the bottom and toggle on/add locations you want to be included for searching. Then reboot.

If it fails to search for files from the locations you just set, see this: [GNOME 3 search bar with no results](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976172/gnome-3-search-bar-with-no-results).